# Laravel Internal Server Error because of Recursive Redirects

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am using a lightsail instance from AWS. It is running an Ubuntu 16.04 AMI. I currently have Laravel 5, and my directory structure looks like this:

```
var
|
+--www
    |
    +--html
        |
        +--laravel
             |
             +--public
```

I mapped the root of my site to the `public` directory using `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public` in the .htaccess file.

My problem is that when I go to my website, I get `Internal Server Error`. When I checked the `error.log` it said that the request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects. After using `Log Level` in the .htaccess file, I found this:
[image]
How can I prevent this?
My .htaccess file can be found
[here](https://pastebin.com/skPjzkiq).

Comment: What if you change this line to include the slash: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public`

Comment: @S.Dev It didn't work. I got the exact same error.

Comment: Try using the rewrite setup that Laravel provide: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: @S.Dev I still got the same error

Comment: Why are you defining the DocumentRoot in an .htaccess file, that is really weird. The DocumentRoot should be defined in an Apache Virtual Host. Never heard about the DocumentRoot defined in an .htaccess file.

Comment: Why don't you try your site using the Laravel `php artisan serve` command? You may run it from your `/var/www/html/laravel/public` dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. This whole issue started because my lightsail instance didn't have enough RAM to run `composer update`. Once I upgraded to a $10/Month plan, with 1 GB of RAM, I was able to run `composer update`, thus fixing my problem.